# OpenGLES for iOS - glBufferData() - GLuint not working for data field

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I have spent half a day trying to resolve this, but I have no luck so far, so I'm looking for some advices and guidance.

I'm rendering a sphere on my 32-bit iPad3 (iOS 8).

```
-(void) bufferVBO :(objectVertex[])objVertices :(int)objectVerticesSize
                  :(GLubyte[])vertexIndices     :(int)vertexIndicesSize
{
    ...
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexIndicesSize, vertexIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    ...
}
```

That works fine. However, that would only render up to 256 indices (since GLubyte is only 8 bit), so I would need more than that to render a sphere.

However, when I attempted this (note the change from "GLubyte" to "GLunit" at the 3rd param):

```
-(void) bufferVBO :(objectVertex[])objVertices :(int)objectVerticesSize
                  :(GLuint[])vertexIndices     :(int)vertexIndicesSize
{
    ...
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexIndicesSize, vertexIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    ...
}
```

That doesn't work. Nothing rendered on my screen. On the (Mac) desktop app, I were able to pass in GLuint to render my sphere no problem. But, on my 32-bit iPad 3, nothing showed up (unless I used GLubyte, which didn't render a full sphere with only 256 indices).

So, why doesn't "GLuint" work for glBufferData() when passing an array of indices? How come only "GLubyte" would work?

Thank you in advance. This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with `glBufferData()`. You can store `GLuint` values in a buffer.

The restriction is that that ES 2.0 does not support `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` as an index type. From the description of the "type" argument of `glDrawElements()` on the [man page](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml):

> Specifies the type of the values in indices. Must be GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE or GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT.

ES 3.0 and full OpenGL support `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` for this argument. There is also an extension for ES 1.x and 2.0 that allows implementations to support it: [OES_element_index_uint](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_element_index_uint.txt).

You can use the `GLushort` type for indices in ES 2.0, with the corresponding value of `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` for the "type" argument of `glDrawElements()`. This gives you a range of 65,536 indices.

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time, to resolve this issue, I use GL_ARRAY_BUFFER instead of GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER to render the sphere, and it works just fine. The downsize is that I needed to buffer more vertices than using indices.